# Please explain the logic behind the truth values of these expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can someone explain the reasoning behind the answers given? We reviewed these in class, but I wasn't able to grasp the logic. Especially c, d, and e.

> The domain of possible values for variables X and Y is {Jim, Ann, Sal, Pat, Tom}. The following facts define the values for which the
>   child predicate is true. The child predicate is false for all other
>   cases.
>
> Evaluate each expression using the domain values and predicates as
>   defined and indicate if the expression is **true** or **false**.
>
> child (Ann,Jim)
>
> child (Sal,Jim)
>
> child (Pat,Ann)
>
> child (Tom,Sal)
>
> ---
>
> a. $(\forall X)$ child$(X,Jim)$
>
> b. $(\exists X)\neg $child$(X,Jim)$
>
> c. $(\forall X)(\exists Y)($child$(X,Jim) \rightarrow $child$(Y,X))$
>
> d. $(\exists Y)(\forall X)($child$(X,Jim) \rightarrow $child$(Y,X))$
>
> e. $(\exists X)(\forall Y)($child$(X,Jim) \rightarrow $child$(Y,X))$

a. FALSE *(Reasoning: Any case that make it false? Yes, so FALSE)*

b. TRUE *(Reasoning: Any case that makes it true? Yes, so TRUE)*

c. TRUE

d. FALSE

e. TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me interpret $child(x,y)$ as "$x$ is a child of $y$", then:

(C) you have to check that every child of Jim has a child, Ann is a child of Jim and Pat is a child of Ann, good. Also Sal is a child of Jim and Tom is a child of Sal, nobody else is a child of Jim, so it is true.

(D) The interpretation of this one would be "there is someone who is a child of every child oj Jim". That someone can not be Jim because Jim is not a child of Ann (and Ann is a child of Jim), it can't
't be Ann because Ann is not a child of Sal, conversely it can't be Sal because Sal is not a child of Ann and finally it can't be Tom because he is not a child of Ann.

(E)The interpretation of this one would be "there is someone who verifies that if she/he is a child of Jim then everybody is a child of her/him", if yoy substitute Jim for your variable $x$ then the implication is true because the antecedent (Jim is a child of Jim) is false, so you found someone who verifies that, and so it is true.

Hope it is clear

Comment: I had to re-read your answer after sleeping on it, but your phraseology now makes more sense (even though I'm still having some difficulty). Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, probably i didn't express it quite well, my english is not so good, i need to improve it... Note that it always get harder to follow the logic structure of a proposition when you increases the number of alternating quantifiers (universal, existential, universal...), there is a whole arithmetic hierarchy behind which classifies the formulas based on their complexity. The typical example is the definition of limit of a function, most students find it hard to grasp at the beggining because we are not used to deal with propositions of our natural languages with three quantifiers alternated.